# Upload multiple files to list without flush other files

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I write code for upload multiple files in my db, it is work, but I cannot find way to add files to list,without remove files that are in list. Every time i choose new files i remove old.

I use:

```
<input type="file" id="i_file" name="file[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;" />
```

Like I say it is work,but problem is that i want to user can choose for example file `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` than when close open dialog, and open it again and load `3.jpg` in some list have `1.jpg`,`2.jpg`,`3.jpg` not only `3.jpg`(this is case now).

It is something like that possible?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Example:-

Div tag that will load a preview of selected files.

```
<input type="file" multiple="true" id="fUpload" />
<div id="file-list"></div>
```

Jquery file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //we apply an event to automatically list of files when the user select the files
        // the files will be built inside a table that includes the file name, size and the upload status.
        $("input#fUpload").change(function () {
            var fileList = "";
            if ($(this).prop("files").length > 0) {
                fileList  = "<table class=\"table-upload\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
                fileList  = "<tr class=\"header-row\">";
                fileList  = "<td class=\"header-filename\">File Name</td>";
                fileList  = "<td class=\"header-filesize\">Size</td>";
                fileList  = "<td class=\"header-status\">Status</td>";
                fileList  = "</tr>";
                for (i = 0; i < $(this).prop("files").length; i++  ) {
                    fileList  = "<tr id=\"row-file" + i + "\" class=\"row-file\">";
                    fileList  = "<td class=\"row-filename\">" +  $(this).prop("files")[i].name   "</td>";
                    fileList  = "<td class=\"row-filesize\">" +  ($(this).prop("files")[i].size / 1048576).toFixed(2) +  " MB</td>";
                    fileList  = "<td id=\"row-status" + i + "\" class=\"row-status\">&#160;</td>";
                    fileList  = "</tr>";
                }
                fileList  = "</table>";
            }

            if (fileList.length > 0) {
                $("#file-list").html(fileList);
                $("#file-list").slideDown();
            }

            for (i = 0; i < $(this).prop("files").length; i++  ) {
                uploadImage(i);
            }
        });
    });

    //This will be the function to post image to generic handler
    //the parameter position will be used to identify which image file is going to be upload
    function uploadImage(position) {
        //we include a random number just to make sure it is unique and not cache.
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10001);

        //we use the FormData object to build the file uploads
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var objFiles = $("input#fUpload").prop("files");
        form_data.append("file", objFiles[position]);

        //we set the status saying the site is currently uploading the file. Note: you can remove the image ajax animated loading if you do not have it and just leave the text information base only. Make sure you set the URL for the generic handler path correctly.
        $("#row-status"   position).html("<img src='ajax-loading.gif'/> Uploading..");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/uploadhandler.ashx?rdm=" + randomnumber,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                //if the post is success it will go here
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //if there is an error it will be here
                //to display an error message you can use xhr.responseText
            },
            complete: function () { 
                //Once the call to generic handler is complete, this will be called.
                //In this case, we want tell the user that the upload is completed.
                $("#row-status"   position).html("Completed"); 
            }
        })
    }

</script>
```

CSS:-

```
<style type="text/css">
.table-upload
{
    min-width:350px;
    border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
    border-left:solid 1px #ccc;    
}

.table-upload td
{
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-right:solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc; 
}

.header-row{
    background:#606264;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#fff;
}
</style>
```

Simple generic handler that will accept any posted file:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="UploadHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string pathSave = context.Server.MapPath("/temp");
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathSave)) {
            try {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathSave);
            } catch {
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++  ){
            HttpPostedFile objHttpPostedFile = (HttpPostedFile)context.Request.Files[i];
            objHttpPostedFile.SaveAs(string.Concat(pathSave, "/", objHttpPostedFile.FileName));
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```